# Syntax error on UNIQUE KEY when creating a table

Tags: mysql, create-table, unique-key

I am trying to create a tabe in a database using the code below. However, it's not working, and I can't figure out why.

The error being generated is a syntax error on `'UNIQUE KEY ID (ID)'`, but according to the tutorial I'm using (and the docs I can find), that looks ok.

I've also tried `'UNIQUE ID (ID)'` and `'UNIQUE ID'`, but I still get the syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE wp_offices (
    ID smallint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    office_created_by smallint(3) DEFAULT "0",
    office_created_date datetime DEFAULT "0000-00-00 00:00:00" NOT NULL,
    office_last_edited_by smallint(3) DEFAULT "0",
    office_last_edited_date datetime DEFAULT "0000-00-00 00:00:00" NOT NULL,
    office_name tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    address_1 tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    address_2 tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    town tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    county tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    postcode tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    telephone tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    fax tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    dx tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    email tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    google_maps text(256) COLLATE latin1_general_ci
)
UNIQUE KEY ID (ID);
```

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be inside the braces

```
google_maps text(256) COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
UNIQUE KEY ID (ID)
);
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. The tutorial I'm using is wrong in that case, but glad it was simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the code for creating table will be

```
   CREATE TABLE wp_offices(
    ID SMALLINT( 3 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    office_created_by SMALLINT( 3 ) DEFAULT "0",
    office_created_date DATETIME DEFAULT "0000-00-00 00:00:00" NOT NULL ,
    office_last_edited_by SMALLINT( 3 ) DEFAULT "0",
    office_last_edited_date DATETIME DEFAULT "0000-00-00 00:00:00" NOT NULL ,
    office_name TINYTEXT COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    address_1 TINYTEXT COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    address_2 TINYTEXT COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    town TINYTEXT COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    county TINYTEXT COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    postcode TINYTEXT COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    telephone TINYTEXT COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    fax TINYTEXT COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    dx TINYTEXT COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    email TINYTEXT COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    google_maps TEXT( 256 ) COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
    UNIQUE KEY ID( ID )
    );
```